# App Engine Configuration Woes

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration, yaml

Trying to configure my java GAE instance via yaml.  The JS library I am using generates a dir structure as part of its build process; I am trying to map urls to the static dir structure.

```
application: scserver
version: 1
runtime: java

handlers:
- url: /static/(.*)/detect-browser
  static_files: static/\1/detect-browser
  upload: static/(.*)/detect-browser
  mime_type: text/javascript

- url: /app/(..)
  static_files: static/app/\1/index.html
  upload: static/app/(.*)/index.html
  mime_type: text/html

- url: /app
  static_files: static/app/en/619741d07103b901ab82148129831c8d1ac0ff8d/index.html
  upload: static/app/en/619741d07103b901ab82148129831c8d1ac0ff8d/index.html
  mime_type: text/html

- url: /static
  static_dir: static  

- url: /app
  static_dir: static/app

-static_files:
  - include: /static/**
```

I get

> Line 7, column 15: Unable to find
>   property 'static_files' on class:
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml$Handler

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely using the [Python yaml configuration](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html) spec.
Have a look to the [Java Application Configuration](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml.html) that has a different syntax.

Comment: you are saying that I am doing it wrong? ;)  How would I do what the above indicates?

Comment: /sys, from the info at this link http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml.html i dont see a way to accomplish this.